# How to remove the white space in ( display:none; -or- clip-bath ) input element?

Tags: css

How I can remove that white space after hiding the element using CSS, here's a screenshot of the issue:

[image: example]

Thank you!

Comment: position:absolute to the element?

Comment: No, after checking I found position:static !important;

Comment: display:none then?

Comment: I tried it but not working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtBCl.png

Comment: Try giving a proper class name to that element and use that in css.

Comment: The problem here is that I'm using Shopify and it's a dynamic button that means I can Enable or Disable it from the settings (Customize theme) and here is the code of button in Liquid language: {% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %} {{ form | payment_button }} {% endif %}

Comment: @James can you share the parent elements of this button from the element tab in chrome? Maybe we can find proper identifier from there.

Comment: `<div role="button" tabindex="0" class="_1LP9NPTft85QosIXd3_zOV _3G6VJhJYno-AX3-X38f1TA _2EiMjnumZ6FVtlC7RViKtj _3DL4HVlgeOhG7Paj6K8DqS" data-testid="PayPalInContext-button"><span class="_11GJAaBiShTVGYuXppoYvE">Buy now with PayPal</span><span aria-hidden="true">Buy with </span><span class="bp01pMHFBVS3SyhYtJKk"><svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" class="h7yAG5cgdBp_GhZjXmVIA" style="height: 18px; width: 63.4737px;"><use xlink:href="#shopify-svg__payments-paypal"></use></svg></span><span aria-hidden="true"></span></div>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215620/discussion-between-harish-sharma-and-james).

Comment: Here is the solution `.shopify-payment-button__button.shopify-payment-button__button--branded {display: none !important}`    

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much bro @HarishSharma for your time and help I really appreciate that! ❤️

Answer (score 0):

add these styles:

```css
visibility: hidden !important;
display: none !important;
opacity: 0 !important;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it's not working :( - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtBCl.png